# Error registering Gitlab Runner in Mac. forbidden

Tags: ios, docker, gitlab, gitlab-runner

I have been trying to register a gitlab runner in my Mac but I keep getting errors saying it is forbidden. I was able to register on windows but for some reason it doesn't work on my Mac.
These are the steps I take:

```
gitlab-runner register \
>   --non-interactive \
>   --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
>   --registration-token "token" \
>   --description "MyApp runner with shell" \
>   --tag-list ios \
>   --executor "shell"
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=darwin pid=3868    revision=98daeee0 version=14.7.0
WARNING: Running in user-mode.                     
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                 
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...                   
                                               
ERROR: Registering runner... forbidden (check registration token)  runner=WswE4
PANIC: Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems.
```

I am using the right token. I tried registering with docker and manually in Mac and both failed. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are registering a GitLab runner to a *secondary* node ([issue 350755](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/350755)) or you have a problem with a reset token ([issue 351114](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/351114)), that seems to be a bug which should be reported.

An [issues search](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues?search=Registering%20runner%20forbidden&sort=created_date&state=opened) does not show many other cases where "Registering runner... forbidden".

Check also [the logs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/faq/) in case of any recorded error message linked to your command there.